# Process Redirect Linux Java

Tags: java, linux, redirect

I have this code that works perfectly in Windows:

```
 //We create the process and pipe it out and in
                    if (isWindows(OS)) {
                        shell="cmd.exe";
                    }
                    else{
                        shell="/bin/sh";
                    }

                    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(shell).redirectInput(Redirect.PIPE)
                            .redirectOutput(Redirect.PIPE).redirectError(Redirect.PIPE);
                    Process process = processBuilder.start();
                    final BufferedReader ProcessIN = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                    final BufferedReader ProcessERROR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
                    final BufferedWriter ProcessOUT = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));
```

The problem is that I want it working on linux/MacOS too and it does not compile because the library `java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect` does not include. 
Is there any equivalent I can use in this case??

Thank you

Comment: If it compiles on one version and not the other, this means you different version of Java,  the OS you are doing it on shouldn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found how to have it working for both OS:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime ().exec (shell);
                    OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream ();
                    InputStream stderr = process.getErrorStream ();
                    InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream ();

                    final BufferedReader ProcessIN = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(stdout));
                    final BufferedReader ProcessERROR = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(stderr));
                    final BufferedWriter ProcessOUT = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stdin));
```